# data not showing in my table angular and springboot

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot

hi  i try to make a list with springboot postgreSQL and angular the backend is working and the data is transfer to the front but the table show empty please anyone can help me
this is my first time using springboot with augular and it's so dificult for me to know the error by my self please helpe i need it today
i want to know where is the problem and how can i fix it so that's my code:

```
`<h1>Consulter Agent</h1>
<table class="styled-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Matricule</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>

            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let agent of agents">
            <td>{{agent.mat}}</td>
            <td>{{agent.FName}}</td>
            <td>{{agent.LName}}</td>
            <td>{{agent.role}}</td>
            
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgentServiceService } from '../agent-service.service';
import { Agent } from '../Agent';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-consulter-agent',
  templateUrl: './consulter-agent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./consulter-agent.component.css']
})
export class ConsulterAgentComponent implements OnInit{
  agents: Agent[]=[];

  constructor(private agentService: AgentServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Getting all agents...');
  this.agentService.getAllAgent()
    .subscribe(agents => {
      console.log('Received agents:', agents);
      this.agents = agents;
    });
  }

  getAgent(): void {
    this.agentService.getAllAgent()
      .subscribe(agents => this.agents = agents);
  }
}
`
```

```
`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Agent } from './Agent';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgentServiceService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9090/agents';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllAgent(): Observable<Agent[]> {
    return this.http.get<Agent[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
`
```

```
`export class Agent {
    mat: number | undefined;
    FName: string | undefined;
    LName: string | undefined;
    
    role:Role | undefined;
  }
  export class Role{
    roleName:String | undefined;
    roleDescription:String | undefined;
  }`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wLOT.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There a huge difference between what is sent from your API and what you THINK an Agent is:

Basicaly you are telling your code that you are receiving an array of Agent objects, but what you are really receiving are array of arrays.

You need to fix your code.

Something like:

```
this.agents = agents.map(agentData => Object.assign(new Agent(), {
  mat: agentData[0],
  FName: agentData[1],
  LName: agentData[2],
  role: Object.assign(new Role(), {roleName: agentData[3]},
});
```

By the way, your template is wrong too: you are trying to display "role", but it is an object, not a string. change it with:

```
{{ role.name }}
```